# Hide clock on lock screen in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, clock

Is there a way to stop the clock from being displayed on the lock screen and on the "charms menubar" in Windows 8?

Comment: no. Not unless you hack around. there may be a registry setting although I doubt that.
Just curious, why would you want that btw? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to hide the clock on the lock screen. [This guide](http://dottech.org/99287/windows-8-how-to-customize-the-clock-on-lock-screen/) shows you how to customize the look of the clock on the lock screen; you can hide the clock by changing the value data to a simple space, or to something else if you wish.

Comment: I tried doing this in win 8.1 and it will not allow a null or a space as a value in the specified registry field.

Answer (score 1):

Windows-L will still lock the desktop and require the user to put in a password (if configured).

There is no way to hide the clock from the lock screen or "Charms" screen. You can (on the Personalization page in Settings) customize what appears below/around the clock on the Lock screen.