# Windows 10 lock screen - Remove date/time

Tags: windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise. I need to show a specific background on the lock screen when a PC is in use remotely. When it does, it will show a kind message that the PC is currently under maintenance. However, I hate the current result because I always see this oversized date/time appearing on my lock screen.

I looked what can be done with GPOs and registry keys but so far no luck.

Would there be a way to remove this, or at least reduce its size if it's there "by design"?

Thanks.

Comment: [Hide clock on lock screen in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/469160/hide-clock-on-lock-screen-in-windows-8) the suggested answer should still work on Windows 10.  I suspect that the only way to properly not show the time and date on the lockscreen will be to disable the lockscreen.

Comment: I can't find the same registry keys that were available for Windows 8/8.1. Still looking.

Answer (score 0):

Some user on Microsoft Community has post the same case, but the Microsoft stuff there said it is by design and can’t be changed.

How to remove windows 10 lock screen clock and date

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-to-remove-windows-10-lock-screen-clock-and/dc045015-cb57-4954-87a7-6762b3361c2f

I notice an user provided a workaround, which does eliminate the clock (by eliminating the entire lock screen), you may be interested in.

RENAME THIS FOLDER:

C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.LockApp_cw5n1h2txyewy

TO SOMETHING LIKE:

C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.LockApp_cw5n1h2txyewy.bak

Comment: If it shows the login screen right away, it's a no-go for us... although if it removes the whole screen but you'd still have to do ctrl-alt-delete, that would be wonderful. I'll give it a try and come back with feedbacks. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not effective on both 1607 LTSC and 1703 SAC builds I have handy (I haven't tried it on 1709, our company has not released it to us yet). I guess it would have worked on previous builds... thanks for your input! I'll continue investigating.